# Equivalence of categories of $D$-modules on a singular $X$

Tags: ct.category-theory, d-modules

Is $D^b(Mod_{qc}(D_X)) \to D^b_{qc}(D_X)$ an equivalence of categories for singular $X$? Where $Mod_{qc}(D_X)$ is the category of quasi-coherent modules on $X$ and $D^b_{qc}(D_X)$ is the full subcategory consisting of objects $Y$ such that $H^j (Y)$ is quasi-coherent for all $j$. This is known to be an equivalence for $X$ smooth, by Ryoshi Hotta
Kiyoshi Takeuchi
Toshiyuki Tanisaki
D-Modules,
Perverse Sheaves,
and Representation Theory Theorem 1.5.7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: the LHS has enough injectives even when $X$ is singular.

Comment: If by $D_X$ you mean the ring of Grothendieck differential operators, then I believe the answer is yes (and that this uses no specific properties of $D_X$, only that it is an associative algebra - this is credited to Bernstein in at least one reference). On the other hand, both categories are very different from the "true" category of $\mathcal{D}_X$-modules for $X$ singular, so I'm not sure if this is really what you are after.

Comment: @dhy, I guess by $Mod_{qc}(D_X)$ i guess I mean $D$-modules on $X$ (following  Kashiwara's lemma). So my question isnt quite right. But it would still be interesting to look at the reference by Bernstein.